# Having 3rd Party or Custom 'Library' references in Domain Model?

Tags: domain-driven-design

If the logic in my domain model depends on a 3rd party component or some in house custom library/manager .dll, is it acceptable to create this dependency? I obviously have no reliance/dependency on the any facade or persistence layers to my domain layer, but I was curious if the other types of dependencies break any rules of DDD?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general I agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13981955/625332), which is especially true if a 3rd party library

- changes often
- does any sort of out-of-process communication
- has a lot of dependencies of its own

However I think that some 3rd party library can be referenced directly from you domain code (otherwise you would not be able to use built-in java/c# types because they can also be considered a 3rd party). These are the libraries that don't have any of the above characteristic, [noda-time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) for example. I can also see how some math or collection libraries can be referenced directly depending on your domain.

Answer (score 4):

In DDD, this type of scenario is handled with an [anti-corruption layer](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/07/07/domain-driven-design-anti-corruption-layer/). What this basically entails is your encapsulate the 3rd party API behind a repository or domain service. You create a local model of the 3rd party API which can then integrate with the rest of your domain layer.